# Xcode cannot find object files

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cmake, xcode10

I have a C++ project that uses CMake that I then use to generate ninja projects that build without issues. I tried to generate an Xcode project but when I try to build it I get an error saying .o files cannot be found:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/build_xcode/src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/connection.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/build_xcode/src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utils.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/build_xcode/src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/state_machines.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/build_xcode/src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/parsers.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/build_xcode/src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/generators.o'
```

Checking the directory shows that these files seem to exist but with different names:

```
> la src/databaseclient.build/Debug/databaseclient.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/                                                                                                     Thu Jan 24 15:14:07 2019
total 23536
drwxr-xr-x  63 ruihpacheco  staff   2.0K Jan 24 15:14 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruihpacheco  staff   128B Jan 24 15:14 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    37K Jan 24 15:14 abstract_connection.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   825K Jan 24 15:14 abstract_connection.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   883K Jan 24 15:14 abstract_connection.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   662B Jan 24 15:14 abstract_result.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   6.8K Jan 24 15:14 abstract_result.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   232K Jan 24 15:14 abstract_result.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    37K Jan 24 15:14 connection-4F0435C11320AC72.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   895K Jan 24 15:14 connection-4F0435C11320AC72.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   610K Jan 24 15:14 connection-4F0435C11320AC72.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   151B Jan 24 15:14 connection-A95D7C1FAB89AE69.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   220B Jan 24 15:14 connection-A95D7C1FAB89AE69.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    50K Jan 24 15:14 connection-A95D7C1FAB89AE69.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    37K Jan 24 15:14 connection-CC26C77ACFAB6964.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   912K Jan 24 15:14 connection-CC26C77ACFAB6964.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   1.0M Jan 24 15:14 connection-CC26C77ACFAB6964.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   2.9K Jan 24 15:14 databaseclient.LinkFileList
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   230B Jan 24 15:14 error_code.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   220B Jan 24 15:14 error_code.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    71K Jan 24 15:14 error_code.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   828B Jan 24 15:14 generators-2BF46CDAE4191A6E.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   8.5K Jan 24 15:14 generators-2BF46CDAE4191A6E.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   218K Jan 24 15:14 generators-2BF46CDAE4191A6E.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   548B Jan 24 15:14 generators-AB4B789D17316956.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   6.8K Jan 24 15:14 generators-AB4B789D17316956.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   415K Jan 24 15:14 generators-AB4B789D17316956.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    36K Jan 24 15:14 listener.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   978K Jan 24 15:14 listener.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   1.2M Jan 24 15:14 listener.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   132B Jan 24 15:14 md5.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   220B Jan 24 15:14 md5.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    95K Jan 24 15:14 md5.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   673B Jan 24 15:14 parsers-404CED0A5A8A6B5B.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   6.7K Jan 24 15:14 parsers-404CED0A5A8A6B5B.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   320K Jan 24 15:14 parsers-404CED0A5A8A6B5B.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   666B Jan 24 15:14 parsers-704FC03E3B6B0880.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   6.4K Jan 24 15:14 parsers-704FC03E3B6B0880.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   501K Jan 24 15:14 parsers-704FC03E3B6B0880.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   222B Jan 24 15:14 result.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   220B Jan 24 15:14 result.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    53K Jan 24 15:14 result.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   134B Jan 24 15:14 sha1.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   648B Jan 24 15:14 sha1.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    82K Jan 24 15:14 sha1.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   149B Jan 24 15:14 sql_state.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   220B Jan 24 15:14 sql_state.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    94K Jan 24 15:14 sql_state.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   903B Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-286E024B50293C5A.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   7.0K Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-286E024B50293C5A.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   357K Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-286E024B50293C5A.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   482B Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-79E86DDB3D33788F.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   6.1K Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-79E86DDB3D33788F.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   200K Jan 24 15:14 state_machines-79E86DDB3D33788F.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   313B Jan 24 15:14 utils-8D3E37120512868D.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   5.5K Jan 24 15:14 utils-8D3E37120512868D.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff    86K Jan 24 15:14 utils-8D3E37120512868D.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   523B Jan 24 15:14 utils-A68FF56E16A77975.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   7.4K Jan 24 15:14 utils-A68FF56E16A77975.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   113K Jan 24 15:14 utils-A68FF56E16A77975.o
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   420B Jan 24 15:14 utils-C6A6E2A9DFE20FA6.d
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   5.8K Jan 24 15:14 utils-C6A6E2A9DFE20FA6.dia
-rw-r--r--   1 ruihpacheco  staff   223K Jan 24 15:14 utils-C6A6E2A9DFE20FA6.o
```

This seems to be an issue with Xcode as my project has several classes called `connection`, `generators`, `parsers`, `state_machines` and `utils` but defined in different namespaces.

Main CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt.")
endif (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "ON")

find_program(CCACHE_PROGRAM ccache)
if(CCACHE_PROGRAM)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CCACHE_PROGRAM}")
endif (CCACHE_PROGRAM)

project(databaseclient LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.1.0.0 DESCRIPTION)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
   set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

add_subdirectory(src)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}>)

# Added here so we can run ctest from the root directory of the project.
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

CMakeLists.txt under src/:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11 FATAL_ERROR)
set(
  INCLUDES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/parameters.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/connection.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/sql_state.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/collation.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/error_code.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/databaseclient/result.hpp
)
set(
  MAIN
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/connection.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sql_state.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/result.cpp
)
set(
  DETAIL
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/types.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/listener.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/listener.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/error_code.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/error_code.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/md5.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/md5.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/sha1.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/sha1.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/utils.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/utils.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/abstract_result.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/abstract_result.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/abstract_connection.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/abstract_connection.cpp
)
set(
  PG
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/connection.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/connection.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/utils.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/utils.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/state_machines.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/state_machines.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/parsers.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/parsers.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/generators.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/pg/generators.cpp
)
set(
  MDB
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/connection.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/connection.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/utils.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/utils.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/state_machines.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/state_machines.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/parsers.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/parsers.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/generators.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/mdb/generators.cpp
)
source_group(
  "include"
    FILES
      ${INCLUDES}
)
source_group(
  ""
    FILES
      ${MAIN}
)
source_group(
  "detail"
    FILES
      ${DETAIL}
)
source_group(
  "detail\\pg"
    FILES
      ${PG}
)
source_group(
  "detail\\mdb"
    FILES
      ${MDB}
)
add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    OBJECT
      ${INCLUDES}
      ${MAIN}
      ${DETAIL}
      ${PG}
      ${MDB}
)
set_target_properties(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
      VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
      POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
)
target_compile_features(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
      cxx_std_11
      cxx_auto_type
      cxx_constexpr
      cxx_deleted_functions
      cxx_inline_namespaces
      cxx_lambdas
      cxx_noexcept
      cxx_nullptr
      cxx_override
      cxx_range_for
)
target_compile_definitions(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
      ASIO_STANDALONE=1
      ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS=1
      ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED=1
)
target_include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
    PRIVATE
      ${byte-lite_SOURCE_DIR}/include/nonstd
      ${asio_SOURCE_DIR}/asio/include/
)

if (UNIX)
  if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -g)
  endif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)

  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wundefined-func-template -Weverything -ferror-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-documentation -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-exit-time-destructors)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
      # -O1 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wthread-safety -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=nullability -fsanitize=address
      target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -glldb -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2)
    endif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
  endif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")

  if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU")
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH_TR1)
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -lstdc++ -rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc48)
  endif (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU")
endif (UNIX)
```

Comment: The issue could be very about XCode, but without your code we can only *guess*. Please, show your code (`CMakeLists.txt`, in form of [mcve]).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added CMake files.

Comment: Hm, it seems to be a problem with `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` working in XCode in case of source files with the same name. Here (at the end of the document) they say about the same limitation: https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rejected/object-libraries.html

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you turn that into an answer?

Comment: I don't use XCode, so I cannot  neither test my guess (about `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` working in XCode) nor to maintain the answer in the future. Feel free to answer your question by yourself; at least you can test that answer. Also, if you think you have found the core of the problem, I would suggest to reduce your code which demonstrates it. So futher readers of your question will be able to easily understand the code and find that they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the OBJECT target and just creating a static library.